# Upgraded TFS 2013 to DevOps 2018. Now the Boards, Backlogs, and Sprints are not working. Error TF400507

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, azure-boards

We upgraded our TFS 2013 server to DevOps 2018 and now when we go to Boards, Backlogs, and Sprints we get the following error:

> TF400917: The current configuration is not valid for this feature. This feature cannot be used until you correct the configuration.
> The following element contains an error: BugWorkItems/BugWorkItems. TF400507: Each work item type must support an initial state value that matches one of the states defined in: BugWorkItems. The following work item types have initial states that do not include any states defined in the bug state configuration: Bug.

I downloaded the processconfig.xml and looked at the BugWorkItems section but it looks correct.

```
  <BugWorkItems category="Microsoft.BugCategory" pluralName="Bugs" singularName="Bug">
    <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="New" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
      <State type="Resolved" value="Resolved" />
    </States>
  </BugWorkItems>
```

I also downloaded the Bug.xml but I don't see anything in the file with the tag "initial state".
So I'm not sure what it means by "must support an initial state value"...

Here is the WORKFLOW section.

```
    <WORKFLOW>
  <STATES>
    <STATE value="Active">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy">
          <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
          <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
    <STATE value="Closed">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
          <READONLY />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
    <STATE value="Code Review">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Custom.Developer">
          <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
          <REQUIRED for="[global]\Developers" />
          <REQUIRED not="[global]\ITProjectManagers" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
    <STATE value="Acceptance Testing" />
    <STATE value="Beta" />
    <STATE value="On Hold" />
    <STATE value="QA Testing" />
    <STATE value="Ready For Beta" />
    <STATE value="Ready For Prod" />
    <STATE value="Requirement" />
  </STATES>
  <TRANSITIONS>
    <TRANSITION from="Closed" to="Active">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Regression" />
        <REASON value="Reactivated" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy">
          <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
          <COPY from="currentuser" />
          <VALIDUSER />
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
          <COPY from="field" field="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank">
          <COPY from="value" value="0" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Beta" to="Active">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Returned to Development" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Active" to="Closed">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Happy Customer" />
        <REASON value="Cancelled" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="currentuser" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="On Hold" to="Active">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Back in Business" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank">
          <COPY from="value" value="0" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="On Hold" to="Beta" for="[global]\ITProjectManagers">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Back in Business" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank">
          <COPY from="value" value="0" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Acceptance Testing" to="Closed" for="[global]\ITProjectManagers">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Happy Customer" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="currentuser" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="QA Testing" to="Beta">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="PASSED QA TESTING" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="QA Testing" to="Active">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Back to Development" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank">
          <COPY from="value" value="0" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Beta" to="Ready For Prod">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Passed Beta - Ready to Deploy" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Active" to="Ready For Beta">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Development is done" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Ready For Beta" to="Active">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Not Ready Yet" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank">
          <COPY from="value" value="0" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Ready For Beta" to="QA Testing">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Ready to be moved to Beta" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Beta" to="On Hold">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Waiting on Resources" />
        <REASON value="Waiting on 3rd Party" />
        <REASON value="Waiting on Development" />
        <REASON value="Waiting on Requirements" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Ready For Prod" to="On Hold">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Waiting on Resources" />
        <REASON value="Waiting on 3rd Party" />
        <REASON value="Waiting on Development" />
        <REASON value="Waiting on Requirements" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="QA Testing" to="On Hold">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Waiting on Resources" />
        <REASON value="Waiting on 3rd Party" />
        <REASON value="Waiting on Development" />
        <REASON value="Waiting on Requirements" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Active" to="On Hold">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Waiting on Requirements" />
        <REASON value="Waiting on Development" />
        <REASON value="Waiting on Resources" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank">
          <COPY from="value" value="1" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Ready For Beta" to="On Hold">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Waiting for Resources" />
        <REASON value="Waiting for Development" />
        <REASON value="Waiting for Requirements" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="" to="Requirement">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="New" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy">
          <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
          <COPY from="currentuser" />
          <VALIDUSER />
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
          <DEFAULT from="value" value="Unassigned User" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank">
          <DEFAULT from="value" value="25" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork">
          <DEFAULT from="value" value="0" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Custom.TestEstimate">
          <DEFAULT from="value" value="15" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Custom.StepsReproduce">
          <REQUIRED for="[global]\Project Collection Valid Users" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Custom.ServiceAgreement">
          <DEFAULT from="value" value="Bug" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps">
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Requirement" to="Active">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Active" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank">
          <COPY from="value" value="0" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Active" to="Code Review">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Code Complete" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Code Review" to="Ready For Beta">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Passed Code Review" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank">
          <COPY from="value" value="0" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Code Review" to="Closed">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Cancelled" />
        <REASON value="Complete" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Requirement" to="Closed">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Cancelled" />
        <REASON value="Complete" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Active" to="Requirement">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Need Requirements" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank">
          <COPY from="value" value="1" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="On Hold" to="Closed">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Cancelled" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="On Hold" to="Ready For Prod" for="[global]\ITProjectManagers">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Ready for Production" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="On Hold" to="Ready For Beta">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Ready to Deploy to BETA" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="On Hold" to="QA Testing">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Ready for QA Testing" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank">
          <COPY from="value" value="0" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Beta" to="Closed">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Cancelled" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="currentuser" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Ready For Prod" to="Closed">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Cancelled" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Ready For Prod" to="Acceptance Testing">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Ready for Acceptance Testing" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Acceptance Testing" to="Ready For Prod" for="[global]\ITProjectManagers">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Back to QA" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Code Review" to="Active">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Back to Developer" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Active" to="Acceptance Testing" for="[global]\ITProjectManagers">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="No Development Required" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
  </TRANSITIONS>
</WORKFLOW>
```

Comment: @jessehouwing Sorry to ask but do you know what section you would need in the Bug.xml? Maybe just the WORKFLOW section? Does "every"  STATE under the WORKFLOW/STATES section need to also exist in the ProcessConfiguration.xml BugWorkItems/States section?  I tried to compare the ProcessConfiguration.xml TaskBacklog/States section to the Task.xml and there are some states in Task.xml that are not in ProcessConfiguration yet Tasks in DevOps seems to be working so I assumed they don't all need to match but I could be wrong.

Comment: @jessehouwing I think we do have some customizations. I inherited this box... I will post the WORKFLOW section in a minute but still for my knowledge, does every STATE in the WORKFLOW have to match a STATE in the ProcessConfiguration BugWorkItems section?

Comment: @jessehouwing I'm sorry but can you post it as an answer to this post? The 3rd line in BugWorkItems says <State type="Proposed" value="New" />. Does it need to be lower case? OR I think you are saying add <STATE value="New"> to the WORKFLOW? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each process in Azure DevOps has 4 meta-states. These higher level states must be mapped to your workflow states in each work item type.

At this point your `BugWorkItems` has these 4 mappings:

```
 <BugWorkItems category="Microsoft.BugCategory" pluralName="Bugs" singularName="Bug">
    <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="New" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
      <State type="Resolved" value="Resolved" />
    </States>
  </BugWorkItems>
```

And of those 4, the state `New` and `Resolved` are missing from your Bug's `WORKFLOW` definition.

You have a few options...

- You can chose to map `Proposed` to an existing workflow state, e.g. `Requirement`.
- You can add the `New` state do the Bug's workflow and transitions.

The same applies to the `Resolved` state.